# Exclude procedure call from transaction rollback

Tags: oracle, transaction, rollback

How can I exclude a statement in a transaction rollback?

```
Begin
Insert into table a
...
...
call proc_1()
...
...
Rollback
```

How can I rollback all the commands except/prevent `proc_1()` from rolling back?

Comment: Isn't it as simple as movimg the proc call to the end of the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the procedure have its on transaction - called an autonomous transaction, but be careful with this one, you can easily get yourself into deadlocks if you use it carelessly without knowing your transactions.

```
create or replace procedure p1 (...) as
  pragma autonomous transaction
begin
  ...
end;
```

Usually this is used for logging purposes.